# Stack Exchange's signup system

Tags: discussion, login

One gotta love the Stack Exchange's registration system; It's so easy and efficient. Creating an account here takes only 2 steps if you have an account in one of the web giants (Google, Facebook etc.)

1. [image]
2. [image]

et viola!

My question is how? Could anyone link me to some sources on how to achieve this epic registration system?

Thanks.

Comment: We are about to roll out some changes to the login form that simplify things now that we can serve the form over SSL - hopefully that goes live next week.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133921/what-openid-solution-is-really-used-by-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

StackExchange uses [OpenID](http://openid.net/). Many other sites support this; e.g. anyone who lets you log in through Facebook (e.g. Spotify), http://unroll.me, etc. If you want to develop a site that uses OpenID, so that you don't have to manage users' credentials, it's straightforward if you follow OpenID's documentation. Anyone can also become an OpenID provider, although relatively few sites accept any OpenID provider, and for good reason - it requires serious security expertise to implement this properly.

[Here is information on how to implement OpenID in Rails yourself](http://railscasts.com/episodes/68-openid-authentication) (Rails since it was the easiest tutorial for me to Google).